# Why color transition is made in different time for elements in one <div>?

Tags: html, css, hover

Inside first  i have paragraph and second (inner)  also with paragraph.

Both of paragraphs have blue text and when mouse is over first  (hover), color changes to red. Color transition is animated.

My problem is that color doesn't change at the same time in both of paragraphs. Second become red after first. I need transition in the same time.

To avoid problem I must move second paragraph from inner  to the first. Or remove star* from CSS (example code below).

In my real case situation is more complicated and I can't move paragraphs from inner . And deleteing star from CSS nothing changes.

Problem is more visible on Chrome than FireFox.

I can't show real example, so below is simple one. But it shows my problem with delaying transition of second paragraph.

```css
.first_div {color: #00f }
.first_div:hover { color: #f00 }
.first_div * { transition: color 800ms linear }
```

```html
<div class="first_div">
  <p>first</p>
  <div>
    <p>second</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can test code on https://jsfiddle.net/xwzt4pyL/2/

How to animate transition of paragraphs in parallel?

Comment: I saw your other question and I will leave this as a comment for you. https://jsfiddle.net/bwsge03u/

Comment: @Huangism Great! Now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this instead

Put the transition on your first div, there is no need to target everything in the first div as the transition will apply everything in it and it will apply it at the same time instead of queuing the transition

```css
.first_div {
  color: #00f;
  transition: color 800ms linear;
}

.first_div:hover {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="first_div">
  <p>first</p>
  <div>
    <p>second</p>
  </div>
</div>
```